# Ubuntu installation Freeze on boot - Intel Skylake Optimus

Tags: ubuntu

I bought a new laptop, it's a msi msi gs60 6qe-025xfr

I'd like to install ubuntu 16.04 on it, but i have a problem.

Every time i try to boot on my USB, i see the loading screen, and suddenly, the PC freeze, and nothing happen...

I tried to boot with my USB key on another computer and it's working...

I think the problem is comming from the CPU, it's a new Skylake model and i saw that ubuntu have compatibility problem with it.

If you can give me some advices...

thx a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you are still having troubles, but for everyone that would need help here is my experience.

I wanted to install ubuntu 16.04 on my asus N552VW with Intel Skylake and Nvidia gtx960m and the installation always freezed after choosing "try ubuntu" or "install ubuntu" so these are the steps I made to solve the problem:

1. I downloaded ubuntu 16.04.2 (which has a 4.8 kernel and not 4.4).
2. At grub level I pressed "e" with the desired option highlighted (ex. install ubuntu) and at the line where you can find "quiet splash" I added "nomodeset". (Each time you boot you need to do this)
3. With ubuntu installed I downloaded and installed Nvidia graphic drivers and Intel graphic drivers.

From this point I could boot normally without using nomodeset, but since the PC would still freeze with fans full speed when using Skylake gpu I needed one more step:

4. Upgrade BIOS version (in my case from 204 to 300)

Now everything works good!
Hope it can help.